# override property value on pom.xml

Tags: maven, jenkins

A part of code in my pom.xml looks like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>${suite.xml}</suiteXmlFile>
        </suiteXmlFiles>
        <properties>
            <property>
                <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
                <value>false</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>listener</name>
                <value>org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter,org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter
                </value>
            </property>
        </properties>
        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
        <systemProperties>
            <property>
                <name>org.uncommons.reportng.title</name>
                <value>${title}</value>
            </property>
        </systemProperties>
        <argLine>-Xms128m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
            -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
        </argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I am sending `-Dtitle` from my jenkins job and it's working fine. Like wise I want to change the value in tag `<testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>`. But the problem here is: I don't want to change the default value. I just want to parameterize this only in case if user provide "false" value from jenkins. If user do not provide anything then it should be "true".

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate profile in pom where you can provide different values.
Plugin definition in pom will contain default value.

So if you run simple maven command : `mvn install` it will use default value
and if you run using profile that is `mvn -Pprofile install` then it will use value specified in profile.

Comment: People who is calling the pom do not want to modify anything in their jenkins job. Only for my job I can change, And I want the condition of "false".

Comment: Its default value as per plugin definition is "false" but I want to use it as "true" as default.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add one property `<maven.test.failure.ignore>true</maven.test.failure.ignore>` under `<properties>` tag of your pom.
2. Replace line testFailureIgnore line by `<testFailureIgnore>${maven.test.failure.ignore}</testFailureIgnore>`.

In case of "false" you need to pass one extra parameter `-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false`

Answer (score 0):

It easy. First you have to add a shell comand to your job. In this command you could make a sed comand an replace this line on the other.

Example:

sed -i 's/ `<maven.test.failure.ignore>true</maven.test.failure.ignore>` /`<maven.test.failure.ignore>false</maven.test.failure.ignore>`/g' pom.xml